# robocopy /mov but don't move files that are in user or opened

Tags: robocopy

I have a simple robocopy syntax:

```
robocopy src dest *.* /MINAGE:7 /MOV
```

My problem is that it moves all files older than 7 days. I made a test with file opened in notepad and it is moving and deleting the file.

I need it to move only the files that are currently not in use (not locked or not opened in another program for editing/writing to file).

Can this be achieved with robocopy?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem - even thou the file is opened in notepad - it was not locked.

But if I go cmd and then use notepad > filename - the it locks the file and robocopy /MOV works as expected.